# Connecting Dreamweaver to EC2 instance hosted website

Tags: amazon-ec2, dreamweaver

I'm fairly new to Dreamweaver and am testing the trial software. I have decent experience with EC2 as i have hosted a website there. I previously used Skybound.ca's Stylizer app for connecting to my site and editing the CSS and storing it to my computer and then building the site and putting it back on server. This worked well for a long time but i ahve kinda outgrown Stylizer app. Can i 'look' at the hosted site on EC2 using the Dreamweaver app and edit the css as a local copy? There seems to be a twisted way of connecting to a site but it is more like edit-local-site-upload-to-remote-server type of paradigm than waht i did with Stylizer. Can anyone point out to me how i can use Dreamweaver the Stylizer way?

The second part of my question is, Dreamweaver connects to EC2 instance, provided a username and password is given. Options range from FTP, SFTP to local network. EC2 instance uses a public key file to be given while connecting using ssh or scp and there is no password involved. I changed my root account to have a password and tried to connect with Dreamweaver but couldn't. I'm leery of doing any changes to ssh file on the instance as i am worried my mistakes will cost me all access to instance. Is there a good way i can connect Dreamweaver to the site?

Any thoughts are appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have experience with Stylizer, but like you said maybe it's time to move on from that. Dreamweaver is pretty user-friendly, and I'm willing to bet you'll be able to do more in Dreamweaver than you could with Stylizer.
That being said, Dreamweaver apparently doesn't use SSH key pairs, BUT there is a workaround I've heard about using "MindTerm" FTP Client. You'll have to create an "FTP-SFTP bridge" or whatever it's called. Check out [this guy's instructions](http://lalor.net/2008/12/dreamweaver-ssh-connections/) on how to do it if you're interested. Once you've done that, you should be able to connect with Dreamweaver. And yes, it's a good idea to have local copies of all your .html, .css, etc. files. That way, you can test things before "going live". And you'll always have a second copy of a file in case you need to revert a change.

**UPDATE:**

So actually, instead of using the MindTerm method for connecting with Dreamweaver, you can experiment with "Adding a New User" to your server that does *not* user ssh key/pairs. I'll explain more if you want. But check out [the beginning of this page](http://utkarshsengar.com/2011/01/manage-multiple-accounts-on-1-amazon-ec2-instance/) for how to add a user. And check out the [response here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=249499#249499) for how to use the `PasswordAuthentication yes` command to "get in" to the server without ssh keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer with the links. I hope Stylizer would up its support a bit and i'd be satisfied. There are a few bugs in Stylizer but they are not deal breaking, just that i've grown a little out of it.

Comment: You're welcome. I was having similar questions myself, so it was timely for me to answer this question anyway. PLUS NOW I HAVE BROKEN 100 REPUTATION WOOHOO :) lol. Seems to me that maybe you could post another question specifically about Stylizer though. or maybe just search the web for info on Dreamweaver to get a better feel for what it can do.

Comment: Note: using Password authentication in SSH is a major security hole with all the SSH password guessing bots out cruising the Internet.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right on that. Seems to me though that you can limit the probability of security issues by allowing only one user to have `PasswordAuthentication yes`. Moreover, you can choose to accept requests only from a certain IP address. So basically, you have `Match Address 192.168.0.* User limitedUser` -- effectively a Logical AND if statement. And we can give `limitedUser` limited privileges so that even if a bot got through in that account, hopefully it wouldn't be able to do much. Seems more secure to me, but I’m no expert.